# Problema al llamar un ImageButton de un Toolbar hacia un Fragment

Tags: java, android

Lo que intento es hacer visible en un Fragment un ImageButton que está contenido en un layout toolbar. Al realizar esta misma acción en una Activity normal no me da ningún problema, pero al hacerlo en el Fragment me da error y recoje el ImageButton como null...

Esto es lo que quiero hacer:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        final View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_service, container, false);

        btnback = (ImageButton) vista.findViewById(R.id.btnback);
        btnback.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getActivity().finish();
            }
        });

return vista;
}
```

LogCat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.matia.tonum.Fragment.ServiceFragment.onCreateView(ServiceFragment.java:55)
                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2346)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1428)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2245)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:703)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, desde ya, muchas gracias!

Comment: que linea es la linea 55 de ServiceFragment.class ?

Comment: @GastónSaillén es esto amigo. btnback = (ImageButton) vista.findViewById(R.id.btnback);
        btnback.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Answer (score 0):

el problema es que en `onCreateView()` solo debes crear la vista y llamar al findView del boton que quieres  para luego utilizarla en `onActivityCreated()`

para solucionarlo saca esto de onCreateView();

```
 btnback.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getActivity().finish();
            }
        });
```

y lo pones en `onActivityCreated()`

```
 btnback.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getActivity().finish();
            }
        });
```

Te explico los dos

**onCreateView ():**

Después de llamar a `onCreate ()` (en el Fragment), se llama a `onCreateView ()` del Fragment. Podes asignar las variables de visualización y hacer cualquier inicialización gráfica. Se espera que devuelva una Vista desde este método, y esta es la vista principal de la interfaz de usuario, pero si el `Fragment` no usa ningún diseño o gráfico, puede devolver el valor null.

**onActivityCreated ():**

Como su nombre lo indica, esto se llama después de que se haya completado la actividad `onCreate ()`. Se llama después de `onCreateView ()` y se utiliza principalmente para las inicializaciones finales (por ejemplo, modificación de elementos de la interfaz de usuario).

Comment: Cómo se podría implementar en el Fragment?, he intentado agregarlo pero sigue sin funcionar... Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: Lo que hice fue esto en onActivityCreated() y me sigue dando error al presionar el botón... 
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
btnback.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getActivity().finish();
            }
        });